# Database design: select-query over function parameters

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I was wondering if something like this could be possible:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE a1 = ... AND a2 = ... AND b1 = ... AND b2 = ...
```

However, what is really happening here is that, I am invoking a DB function, like:

```
func1(a1,a2);
```

Which returns a type:

```
(b1,b2)
```

So, the idea is that from the end-user’s perspective, it feels like we’re just querying a table as we normally do, however, the function call and the resulting query-selection is hidden from the user and done behind the scenes.

Any help in order to suggest a possible design in the DB that could accomplish this, would be much appreciated. (For example, table1 could be some kind of virtual table or view).

Comment: You'll need to specify your database platform.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to provide a the exact query you've got.

The closest I managed is just to call the function in the from clause.  The syntax is different, and you're specifying function parameters in the function call instead of the where clause.

eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfun(a1 INT, a2 INT)
RETURNS TABLE (b1 int, b2 int)
AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY (SELECT a1+a2 AS b1, a1*a2 AS b2);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which lets us call

```
select * from myfun(4,5);

b1   b2
---- ----
9    20
```

I did have a look at the Postgresql [Rule](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/rules.html) system which might be able to rewrite the query and move the parameters from the where clause into a function call, but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your database platform, I can only speculate.

In SQL Server, you write a [Table Valued Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175924%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (TVF).

PostgreSQL appears to [support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createfunction.html) this as well.

You would evaluate `a1` and `b1` within the function itself. The outer select would only be concerned with `b1` and `b2` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: How about PostgreSQL, which is what I’m using?

Comment: It looks like you can return a table value from a function in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: Could you please extend your answer to perhaps provide an example of how this could be solved, using the scenario as I specified, thnx.

Comment: @Larry take a stab at it yourself so I can see where you are having problems.

Comment: Ok, but using this, is it possible as I mentioned to allow the user to specify the values of a1 and a2 via the WHERE clause, or do they still have to pass them in as function parameters, like table1(a1,a2). Because, I really wanted a solution like the former, please advise...

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures in most databases can return a set of rows.

To that end, a stored function in PostgreSQL can [return a cursor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) (see the "Returning Cursors" section).

Comment: thanks, but could you explain further how this can be used, or give a small example using the original question.

Comment: @Larry You mentioned that "the resulting query-selection is hidden from the user and done behind the scenes". So, you can hide a query inside a function returning a cursor (or RETURNS TABLE as RedFilter suggested)...

Comment: I hope I didn’t mislead in the question, but what I am trying to get at is that I still would like the user to specify parameter names and values via the WHERE clause, but this is then parsed appropriately (i.e. some may be a function call, some may be used for query-selection, which is what I meant ‘behind-the-scenes’). But could you please confirm, is it still possible to allow users to use the WHERE clause for params? (if so, that is exactly what I need, I will look much further into the suggestions made). Thanx!

Comment: @Larry It seems you need some form of dynamic SQL. You should be able to dynamically construct and execute your SQL statement inside the function, thus hiding the "guts" from the client.

Comment: ok thanks, I was just wondering you think you could find an example somewhere that demonstrates the main concepts here, I think that would help a lot.